# What is wrong with the second proof?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Let $f$ be a real-valued function continuous on an interval $I$ and differentiable on every interior point of $I.$ Then if $f'(x)\ge 0$ everywhere inside $I,$ $f$ does not decrease over $I.$

There's this proof using MVT: Let $x<y$ be arbitrary numbers in $I,$ then there is a $c\in (x,y)$ such that $$f'(c)=\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}.$$ But since $f'(c)\ge 0$ and $y-x>0,$ this gives $f(y)-f(x)=f'(c)(y-x)\ge 0,$ so that $f(y)\ge f(x)$ on $I.$

I tried proving the contrapositive, and ended up with something quite unsatisfactory. Here's what I did. I assumed that $f$ decreases on $I,$ then applied MVT too: Thus, with notation as above, we have $$f'(c)=\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$$ for arbitrary $c\in (x,y),$ with $x$ and $y$ also being arbitrary. However, since $f$ decreases, it follows that $f'(c)<0,$ which is the conclusion we should have, too.

However, I noticed that this fails for some example. I just applied this to $-x^3,$ which decreases everywhere, but whose derivative $-3x^2$ fails to be negative at $x=0,$ as expected. What is happening here?

As a sanity check, this does not happen for $x^3$ using the first version of the theorem. So, what is wrong with the contrapositive, or its proof?

Thanks.

Comment: The way this is phrased, the negation of "$f$ does not decrease on $I$" is not "$f$ decreases on $I$". Or, at the very least, you have to look very carefully at what's going on there.

Comment: You get the existence of a point $c$ such that $f'(c) < 0$; why do you think that $c$ must be equal to $0$?

Comment: @Arthur Why isn't this the negation, and what would you propose?

Comment: @TheoBendit I don't think $c=0.$ I said that for $-x^3,$ we get $f'(x)=0$ when $x=0,$ contrary to the expectation that $f'(x)<0$ everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if "$f$ decreases on $I$", then "$f'(x) \ge 0$ everywhere inside of $I$" no longer fully applies. In particular, this hypothesis means that $f'(x) \lt 0$ at least **somewhere** in $I$, but not necessarily everywhere. With your example of $f(x) = -x^3$, even though it's always decreasing over any range, you've seen that the derivative may be $0$, which is due to it being an inflection point there, even though the derivative is negative everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks. Your first paragraph answers my question, I think. However, your second is irrelevant. As I said to the person who first made that insinuation, I do not think so (and you can reread OP to verify this). It simply happens to be the case with the example I picked. I don't know who misread this first, but this completely misrepresents what I actually wrote, while it is still in plain view. Thank you as you edit appropriately so I can close the question.

Comment: I'm glad my first paragraph answers your question. Also, I'm sorry for having misunderstood what you wrote. As I believe you've requested, I have removed my second paragraph in my answer. Does this resolve the issue for you?

Comment: Yes. I am grateful.

Comment: I have a further suggestion. You might have made a mistype in thinking it was the antecedent of my negation that was wrong, whereas I made the mistake in the consequent part of the negation, not the first part as you thought: I should have got, *If $f$ decreases on $I,$ then **somewhere** in $I$ we have $f'(x)<0.$* I made the mistake in the universal quantifier in the first part of the original theorem.

Comment: I've changed the wording somewhat. Is this now satisfactory to you?

Comment: I was pointing out that the negation of *$f'(x)\ge 0$ **everywhere** ...* was what I actually missed, not the negation of *$f$ does not decrease over $I.$* No problem anyway since I already spotted my error. Just said to let you know. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. I appreciate you explaining what it was that you actually originally missed.

Answer (score 0):

You're making an error with the quantifiers. Saying that “it is not the case that $f$ does not decrease” is not the same as “$f$ decreases”.

The negation of “$f$ does not decrease” is

> there exist $x,y\in I$ such that $x<y$ and $f(x)>f(y)$

The mean value theorem tells you that, for some $c\in(x,y)$,
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=f'(c)
$$
so that $f'(c)<0$.

Comment: Thanks, but I already understood where I went wrong. Furthermore, if it is anything, by $f$ not decreasing I mean that *whenever $x\lt y$ in $I$ we have $f(x)\le f(y).$* Clearly, the negation of that is that *if $x\lt y,$ then $f(x)\gt f(y),$* which means $f$ decreases. I made the mistake with the first part of the original statement. Once again, thanks.

Comment: Or, shortly, the negation of $A \implies B$ is $A\implies \sim B.$